# Resume - Do publications matter for Engineering Works?

Tags: resume

I have been working in academia (software engineering research) for several years now and I have collaborated in numerous papers.

Now I would like a job in the industry, specifically as a Software Engineer and I'm wondering whether to include the list of publications in my resume, since it make my resume two pages long.

Is this to my advantage, HR won't care at all or is it counterproductive?

Comment: what sort of jobs and employers  are you applying for?  it makes a huge diference

Comment: Does your list of publications have anything to do with the positions you are applying for? If not, you're just adding more stuff for people to have to go through.

Comment: @Neuromancer I'm applying for big companies like Intel, Microsoft and the sort.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan Yes, they do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that HR and your future bosses will want to know as efficiently as possible if you're fit for the job.
In that respect I think you should mention chosen publications, in particular those fulfilling as many of certain criteria as possible: The field you worked in is relevant for the job, you played a main role in the research, you still remember well what you did there (and can respond well in case they ask detail questions about it).
Pick about 3-5 such publications and mention the rest as a summary (for instance say the number of others or a plain list of just the titles, or add a link to a website where they could see them all, perhaps even download and read them if they're interested).

In general there are no strict rules how a resume should be, but most of the time facts count higher than attributes you give yourself. So instead of writing a lot about who you are and how well you're team-oriented and such phrases give them a really good list of your former works. If that's research, then it's research.